# Prevent parsing a JSON node with common-lisp YASON library

Tags: json, common-lisp

I am using the Yason library in common-lisp, I want to parse a json string but would like the parser to keep one a its node unparsed.
Typically with an example like that:

```
{
 "metadata1" : "mydata1",
 "metadata2" : "mydata2",
 "payload" : {...my long payload object},
 "otherNodesToParse" : {...}
}
```

How can I set the yason parser to parse my json but skip the payload node and keep it as a string in the json format.

Use: let's say I just want the envelope data (everything that's not the payload), and  to forward the payload as-is (as json string) to another system.

If I parse the whole json (so including payload) and then re-encode the payload to json, it is inefficient. The payload size could also be pretty big.

Comment: I think this is not possible. From the documetation inside the library: “JSON data is always completely parsed into an equivalent in-memory representation.” Maybe you could try [other packages](https://github.com/CodyReichert/awesome-cl#json)

Comment: The fact is that you still somehow need to parse the input to determine where your payload starts and where it ends; YASON does not provide it out of the box, but you could hack the library to e.g. parse objects as nothing. With "lisp-binary" or with "protobuf" you could encode arbitrary bytes + length in a message and only decode it when necessary. Maybe JSON is not the best format in your case. Another thing to consider: first try it the obvious way (decode all), and measure to determine if you really have performance problems.

Comment: so, what you want is to not convert all parts to Lisp data, but keep parts of a JSON expression as a string. This means that you still need to parse the whole thing, to find the end. Note that you also might need to freshly allocate these (sub)strings.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

How do you know where the end of the payload object is in the stream?  You do so *by parsing the stream*: if you don't parse the stream you simply can't know where the end of the object is: that's the nature of JSON's syntax (as it is the nature of CL's default syntax).  For instance the only way you can know the difference between where to continue after

```
{x:1}
```

and after

```
{x:1.2}
```

is by parsing the two things.

So you must necessarily parse the whole thing.

So the answer to your question is: you can't do this.

---

You could (but not, I think, with YASON) decide that you did not want to build an object as a result of the parse.  And perhaps, if the stream you are parsing  corresponds to something with random access like a string or a file, you could note the start and end positions in the stream to later extract a string from it corresponding to the unparsed data (or you could perhaps build it up as you go).

It looks as if some or all of this might be possible with [CL-JSON](https://common-lisp.net/project/cl-json/cl-json.html), but you'd have to work at it.

Unless the objects you are reading are vast the benefit of this seems questionable-to-none.  If you really do want to do something like this efficiently you need a serialisation scheme which tells you how long things are.

Comment: I think I see how to do this with CL-JSON handler. YASON was in my requirement because it was already used in some other part of code I share.

But at the end, I think @coredump is right, I should measure at runtime to see if I end up with performance problems before going into that (For the moment, I decode the full JSON document to reencode back in JSON the subnode I want - that being inefficient by logical point of view, but perhaps not that much from empirical point of view).